# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNBranch.STANDARD EVENT ADD_TO_CART')

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, cocoapods

I've upgraded React Native from 54.4 to 57.7 and whenever I try to run the app and launch simulator, the build works but I'm getting an `Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNBranch.STANDARD EVENT ADD_TO_CART')` error.

These are the things i've done:

1. reinstalled cocoa pods `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. removed pods `pod deintegrate /Users/cam/myapp/ios/Hooch.xcodeproj`
3. I cleaned then installed `pod clean` and `pod install`
4. I've gone to my podfile, and added `pod "react-native-branch", path: "../node_modules/react-native-branch"
   pod "Branch-SDK", path: "../node_modules/react-native-branch/ios"`
5. I've gone to the BranchEvent.js and removed all commerce events, and gone to index.js and removed the variables but no luck.

I can't figure out if this is a pods issue or a branch issue and nothing else I can think of seems to be working.

Anyone have any thoughts on what it could be?

[image]

Comment: how did you upgrade? upgrading subversion numbers is almost never as simple as editing your package.json, upgrading from 54 to 57 is almost certainly going to be a more complicated affair. At the very least make sure your react and react-test-renderer versions are correct, but you could also be missing some core native files or changes to core native files in your project, you can see a history of those changes here https://github.com/ncuillery/rn-diff

Comment: First thing I did was edit the package.json to upgrade version of react and react-test-renderer to 16.6.3  `npm install --save react@16.6.3 `, `npm install --save react-test-renderer@16.6.3 `.

then i updated RN via git `npm install -g react-native-git-upgrade`. Then, I found the upgrade patch and applied it
`git apply $TMPDIR/react-native-git-upgrade/upgrade_0.54.4_0.57.8.patch`

Comment: Did you have any luck with this in the end @CameronD.Burley? Hitting the same error but with `null` instead of `undefined`. We've only just added `react-native-branch` to our project.

Comment: Figured my issue out. We needed to add and link the RNBranch SDK directly in Xcode.